# Data Call with AT commands failed

Tags: at-command, 3g, modem, 3g-network, dial-up

I'm using at commands to connect with a 3g modem to internet. All messages show that all is OK but there no internet acces and modem status in windows 7 is disconected. The led from the modem in on like it is connected to internet.
The commands that i`m using are(in this order):

> COM5 115200 4000
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGREG?
>   +CGREG: 0,1 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGREG=?
>   +CGREG: (0-2) OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGREG?
>   +CGREG: 0,1 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+COPS?
>   +COPS: 0,2,"22603",0 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CSQ
>   +CSQ: 21,99 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGATT=1 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","broadband" OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGACT=1,1 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CEER
>   +CEER: No cause information available OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGACT?
>   +CGACT: 1,1 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGATT?
>   +CGATT: 1 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGREG?
>   +CGREG: 0,1 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGDCONT?
>   +CGDCONT: 1,"IP","broadband","0.0.0.0",0,0 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGACT=0,1 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CEER
>   +CEER: No cause information available OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+COPS?
>   +COPS: 0,2,"22603",0 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CSQ
>   +CSQ: 21,99 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGATT=1 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","broadband" OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGACT=1,1 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CEER
>   +CEER: No cause information available OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGACT?
>   +CGACT: 1,1 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGATT?
>   +CGATT: 1 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGREG?
>   +CGREG: 0,1 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGDCONT?
>   +CGDCONT: 1,"IP","broadband","0.0.0.0",0,0 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CGACT=0,1 OK
>
> CODE INTRODUCED: AT+CEER
>   +CEER: No cause information available OK

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably establishing the connection on the device won't be sufficient as windows will not be notified of the connection. You should setup a modem in Windows and use this to establish the connection.

[DotRas](https://dotras.codeplex.com/) ist a project to do exactly this in c#. But there may be other solutions for other languages as well. If you are scripting you can have a look at WMI. There are classes for modems as well.

Answer (score 1):

I`ve found the answer to my question. To connect to internet through a 3g modem you need to create a dial-up sesion or to use one existing. The easiest way in visual C# is to use DotRas library and create de dial-up. 
Example

```
private void connectbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
            string path = RasPhoneBook.GetPhoneBookPath(RasPhoneBookType.User);
            RasPhoneBook pbk = new RasPhoneBook();
            pbk.Open(path);
            RasDevice modem = RasDevice.GetDeviceByName("HUAWEI Mobile Connect - 3G Modem",RasDeviceType.Modem);
           //get the exact device name from windows
            RasEntry entry = RasEntry.CreateDialUpEntry("Broadband", "*99#", modem);
            entry.Options.RemoteDefaultGateway = true;
            if (RasEntry.Exists("Broadband", path) == false)
            { pbk.Entries.Add(entry); }
            RasDialer dialer = new RasDialer();
            dialer.EntryName = "Broadband";
            dialer.PhoneBookPath = path;
            dialer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();

            dialer.Credentials.Domain = "broadband";
            dialer.PhoneNumber="*99#";
            dialer.Dial();

        }
```

Take care the setting you have for your connection to work and ghet internet acces.

Comment: It would be better to include this information in an update to your question. This would help others to find the solution you actually used.